# Android application No Save Game == "Unfortunately, activity ended"

Tags: android, eclipse, inputstream, bufferedreader, outputstream

Developing an app using eclipse for 4.4.2 (KitKat)

Made a game which reads from a save file onCreate(), however, I also included functionality to wipe that save file, using deleteFile(File_Name), but for some reason, when I wipe the file, the main activity will no longer load.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the method by which I'm error catching:
here is the snippet that I remove for the app to work, but put back in and it fails to load.

```
/* try {// to open the file
        inputStream = openFileInput(FILE_NAME); 
        try {//to read the file
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            String inputString;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputString );
            }// End of reading file
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "HighScore = \n" + stringBuffer.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String hiscoremessage = stringBuffer.toString();
            highscore = Integer.parseInt(hiscoremessage);
            tvHighScore.setText(hiscoremessage);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {// Problem reading file
            Log.e("TAG", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("TAG", "File not found: " + e1.toString());
    } */
```

Comment: Any exception you are getting?

Comment: No no, neither exceptions are returning, however, I have reverted to a backup, and now THAT is having similar problems.

Comment: what this method does openFileInput? When you say activity fails to load what excatly that means.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Debugged all hell out of it, realized the file that inputs the save game was loading from stringbuffer to string as NULL, throwing an exception, exception handling for null, populating native variables as 0 for the catch solved the issue.